# while loop not looping past 1

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, conditional-statements, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use a `while` loop in Perl that takes one argument from command line, which is the number of hellos to print on the string. I wrote the following:

```
# Basic settings to catch errors
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define subroutine containing the program
sub WhileNumbers {
    
    # read script arguments
    my $numberOfhellos = @ARGV;
    chomp($numberOfhellos);
    
    # Loop through the files
    my $counts = 1;
    while($counts <= $numberOfhellos) {
        # Get user input the protein of interest
        print ("Hello number $counts \n");
        
        $counts ++;
        
    }
    

}

# Calling the subroutine
WhileNumbers();
```

When I run:
`$ perl hellos.pl 3`

I get as output:

> Hello number 1

While in reality I would like:

> Hello number 1
>
> Hello number 2
>
> Hello number 3

Any clue why the while loop is not working as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my $numberOfhellos = @ARGV;
```

You're assigning an array to a scalar variable. What this gives you is the number of elements in the array. Since you're passing a single argument (`3`) to your script, i.e.

```
@ARGV = ("3")
```

this sets `$numberOfHellos` to `1`.

The fix is to set `$numberOfhellos` to the first element of `@ARGV`, as in:

```
my $numberOfhellos = $ARGV[0];
```

or alternatively,

```
my ($numberOfhellos) = @ARGV;
```

which (because of the parentheses) performs list assignment, which stores the first element of `@ARGV` in the first element of the list on the left-hand side, i.e. it also ends up setting `$numberOfhellos = $ARGV[0]`.

Also, you don't need this:

```
chomp($numberOfhellos);
```

`chomp` is used to remove a trailing newline character from a string returned from the `readline` function. There are no newlines involved here.

---

That said, a more idiomatic way to write a counting loop in Perl is to use `for` (and a range) instead of `while`:

```
my $numberOfHellos = $ARGV[0];

for my $count (1 .. $numberOfHellos) {
    print "Hello number $count\n";
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. At times I get confused with these declarations #newtoPerl  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do

> ```
> ...
> my $numberOfhellos = @ARGV;
> ...
> ```

scalar context is used and `$numberOfhellos` gets the number of elements in `@ARGV` assigned, which is `1` if you passed one argument.

Explicitly assign the first element to the variable.

```
...
my $numberOfhellos = $ARGV[0];
...
```

There also is no need for `chomp()` there. You might confuse `@ARGV` with `<STDIN>` or similar. But it wouldn't harm to check for the arguments being what you expect. That is check their number and if the first one is an integer. Something like:

```
...
my $numberOfhellos;
if (scalar(@ARGV) == 1
    && $ARGV[0] =~ m/\A[0-9]+\z/) {
    $numberOfhellos = $ARGV[0];
}
else {
    die("Wrong arguments");
}
...
```

Note that `scalar(@ARGV)` forces scalar context on `@ARGV` resulting in its number of elements. I.e. the same that happened in your original assignment.

Comment: `==` already evaluates its operands in scalar context; `scalar( )` is redundant here.

Comment: `m/^\d+$/` allows quite a few unexpected strings (e.g. Unicode digits or trailing newlines). Better: `m/\A[0-9]+\z/`.

Comment: @melpomene: Hmm, never thought of that but you're right. But using `scalar` more explicitly demonstrates whats going on there. So I'll leave that and upvote your comment.

Comment: @melpomene: Changed the regexp as suggested.